# What is the purpose of the Create directory used by Tarantino?

Tags: data-migration, tarantino

[Tarantino](https://github.com/HeadspringLabs/Tarantino) requires that you point it to a scripts directory that contains two subdirectories, create and update. When Tarantino's create or rebuild action is executed I expected sql scripts in the create directory to be run, followed by, in the case of the rebuild action, any scripts in the update directory.

I've found that scripts in the create directory are never executed; all my scripts are required to be in the update directory.  Additionally, the examples I've found online all use the update directory exclusively.  So what is the purpose of the create directory and how is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Tarantino is looking for an "ExistingSchema" subdirectory instead of a "Create" subdirectory.  I believe the documentation is just out of date.

When performing the Create action, scripts in the ExistingSchema directory are executed, followed by scripts in the Update directory.

An Update action only executes scripts in the Update directory.

The Rebuild action behaves like the create action but drops the database first.